# Combining ng-grid and ui.bootstrap.modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-grid

I'm trying to put `ng-grid` on the modal window (ui.bootstrap.modal). When grid placed on the main page, everything is ok.

But when I place it into

```
<script type="text/ng-template"...></script>
```

I'm getting the following:

> "TypeError: Cannot set property 'gridDim' of undefined".

Is there some workaround to place `ng-grid` on a modal window?

My plunk is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/ctLF6j3WeqSvT3vEM40f?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://plnkr.co/edit/SkqwlmfSM6jpgS9rR5Ad

```
var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

$scope.gridOptions = { 
    data: 'myData',
    columnDefs: [{field: 'name', displayName: 'Name'}, {field:'age', displayName:'Age'}, {field: 'remove', displayName:'', cellTemplate: removeTemplate}]
};
$scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                 {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                 {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                 {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                 {name: "Enos", age: 34}]; 
  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.items[0]
  };

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
};
```

The modal has it's own scope not inheriting from the scope where you defined the gridOptions, this error occurs if it can't find the gridOptions to set the gridDim on it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I suspected that the point somewhere in scopes relationship.

Comment: Yup I've just messed with the grid enough to know that error unfortunately.

Comment: Instead of using a fixed width for the ng-grid (400px), maybe its nicer for the user (but also uglier for the code) to do this after loading the data: `$(window).resize();`